# Find records older than 30 days in oracle sql

Tags: oracle, syntax-error

I am working in Oracle BI with some SQL and trying to find results for a date range from the beginning of last month to 30 days old from today's date.  I have looked through all the similar articles on here and tried their coding and none of them worked.  This is the latest I have:

FROM "**NAME**" WHERE "Day Dimension"."Start Date" <= TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY, -30, DATE'@{day}')

This seemed to get me the closest but Oracle did not recognize the '@{day}' criteria.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For OBIEE reports:

```
timestampadd(SQL_TSI_DAY,-30,CURRENT_DATE)
```

(OR)

```
SYSDATE, cast(EVALUATE('SYSDATE-30') as timestamp)
```

For SQLPLUS, Try this- SYSDATE will return the current date; subtract 30 for the number of days:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  DATE_FIELD < SYSDATE-30;
```

References:

http://oracle.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/oracle-bi-l/how-to-use-sysdate-function-in-obiee-reports-4291644

Comment: Thank you but no this did not work  I get the error "Unresolved column" for SYSDATE. It doesn't recognize it.

Comment: I added 2 commands for OBIEE reports; the original command was for SQLPLUS- will either of those 2 commands work? Thanks

Comment: First one worked....I needed the CURRENT_DATE...I had tried nearly every other one.  THANK YOU!